# Django ModelForms: Display ManyToMany field as single-select

Tags: django, django-forms

In a Django app, I'm having a model Bet which contains a ManyToMany relation with the User model of Django:

```
class Bet(models.Model):
    ...
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

User should be able to start new bets using a form. Until now, bets have exactly two participants, one of which is the user who creates the bet himself. That means in the form for the new bet you have to chose exactly one participant. The bet creator is added as participant upon saving of the form data.

I'm using a ModelForm for my `NewBetForm`:

```
class NewBetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bet
        widgets = {
            'participants': forms.Select()
        }

    def save(self, user):
        ... # save user as participant
```

Notice the redefined widget for the participants field which makes sure you can only choose one participant.

However, this gives me a validation error:

```
Enter a list of values.
```

I'm not really sure where this comes from. If I look at the POST data in the developer tools, it seems to be exactly the same as if I use the default widget and choose only one participant. However, it seems like the `to_python()` method of the ManyToManyField has its problems with this data. At least there is no User object created if I enable the Select widget.

I know I could work around this problem by excluding the participants field from the form and define it myself but it would be a lot nicer if the ModelForm's capacities could still be used (after all, it's only a widget change). Maybe I could manipulate the passed data in some way if I knew how.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is exactly and if there is a good way to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

As suggested in the comments: the (relevant) code of the view.

```
def new_bet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewBetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request.user)
            ... # success message and redirect
    else:
        form = NewBetForm()
    return render(request, 'bets/new.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging in the Django code, I can answer my own question.

The problem is that Django's ModelForm maps `ManyToManyField`s in the model to `ModelMultipleChoiceField`s of the form. This kind of form field expects the widget object to return a sequence from its `value_from_datadict()` method. The default widget for `ModelMultipleChoiceField` (which is `SelectMultiple`) overrides `value_from_datadict()` to return a list from the user supplied data. But if I use the `Select` widget, the default `value_from_datadict()` method of the superclass is used, which simply returns a string. `ModelMultipleChoiceField` doesn't like that at all, hence the validation error.

To solutions I could think of:

1. Overriding the `value_from_datadict()` of `Select` either via inheritance or some class decorator.
2. Handling the m2m field manually by creating a new form field and adjusting the `save()` method of the `ModelForm` to save its data in the m2m relation.

The seconds solution seems to be less verbose, so that's what I will be going with.

Answer (score 3):

I don't mean to revive a resolved question but I was working a solution like this and thought I would share my code to help others.

In j0ker's answer he lists two methods to get this to work. I used method 1. In which I borrowed the 'value_from_datadict' method from the SelectMultiple widget.

forms.py

```
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict, MergeDict

class M2MSelect(forms.Select):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        if isinstance(data, (MultiValueDict, MergeDict)):
            return data.getlist(name)
        return data.get(name, None)    

class WindowsSubnetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    port_group = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=M2MSelect, required=True, queryset=PortGroup.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Subnet
```

Comment: `MergeDict` was removed at some point from Django. Why did you check both `MultiValueDict` and `MergeDict` and not simply `MultiValueDict`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ManyToMany is the wrong data type for this relationship.

In a sense, the bet *itself* is the many-to-many relationship. It makes no sense to have the participants as a manytomanyfield. What you need is two ForeignKeys, both to User: one for the creator, one for the other user ('acceptor'?)

Comment: The idea behind the m2m relationship is that it will be possible to extend the functionality to bets with more than two participants later. So I think, m2m is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the submitted value before (during) validation in `Form.clean_field_name`. You could use this method to wrap the select's single value in a list.

```
class NewBetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bet
        widgets = {
            'participants': forms.Select()
        }

    def save(self, user):
        ... # save user as participant

    def clean_participants(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['participants']
        return [data]
```

I'm actually just guessing what the value proivded by the select looks like, so this might need a bit of tweaking, but I think it will work.

[Here are the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

Comment: I still tried that. It doesn't work because `clean_participants()` is never called. The form seems not to be able to create the Python User object, so it fails already before. If I try to override the `clean()` method, `self.cleaned_data['participants']` is not set.

Comment: `ModelForm.save` takes no parameters. I copied your save method, but unless you're doing something non-standard, the signature should just be `save(self)`.

Comment: `save(self, user)` is no override but a new method that calls `super(...).save()` and than saves the passed user as participant (plus something more).

Comment: I added the view code. As for the stack trace I have no idea how to get that, since Django is dealing with form ValidationErrors internally.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Ryan Currah I found this to be working out of the box:

```
class M2MSelect(forms.SelectMultiple):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        rendered = super(M2MSelect, self).render(name, value=value, attrs=attrs, choices=choices)
        return rendered.replace(u'multiple="multiple"', u'')
```

The first one of the many to many is displayed and when saved only the selected value is left.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easyer way to do this inspired by @Ryan Currah:
You just have to override "allow_multiple_selected" attribut from SelectMultiple class

```py
class M2MSelect(forms.SelectMultiple):
    allow_multiple_selected = False


class NewBetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bet

    participants = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=M2MSelect, required=True, queryset=User.objects.all())
```