# Replacing ManyToMany-Relation with ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm stuck trying to render a ManyToMany-Relation as a ModelChoiceField instead of a ModelMultipleChoiceField. So I tried the following (simplified):

```py
models.py:

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    manager = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="manager_related")

forms.py:

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    manager = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
                               empty_label='Choose Manager', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'manager']
```

The form renders correctly and I can select a registered user from the list. But after submitting the form, I'll get a `TypeError` with the message `'User' object is not iterable`. I think that the save() function needs two values to save a ManyToMany-Relation but the ModelChoiceField returns only one. I don't know how to solve that...

Comment: Will there only ever be one manager? If yes, why have a many to many at all?

Comment: Well, the question is justified. I think I will have multiple Managers, as well as Editors and Guests and so on. But I'm currently evaluating different approaches to display the project configuration to the application user. And one possible solution is the one from the question.

Comment: Ok so you want to be able to add multiple managers, but in this form you just want to be able to select one? If this is used to update a project, what will happen to all the other managers?

Comment: you're right - for updating the project I need another mechanism. Anyway, I still would like to know how to save a M2M-relation which is rendered as a Select-Widget. The approach of Wtower doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around I got an working solution. Wtowers proposal is not working. Why? Read that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336492/2153744

So we have to handle everything on our own.

**forms.py**

```
# helper class: returning full_name instead of username
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_full_name()


class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    manager = UserModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), label='Manager', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name']
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # get cleaned data from form
        prj_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        prj_manager = form.cleaned_data['manager']  # this is a User-object

        # generate project and store it to db
        prj = Project(name=prj_name)
        prj.save()

        # handling now m2m relation for manager
        prj.manager.add(prj_manager)

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/project/list")

else:
    form = ProjectForm()
```

Comment: That post is 3 years old. I am sorry that it did not work for you, I use it extensively myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with this by changing the widget:

forms.py:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'manager']
        widgets = {
            'manager': forms.Select(),
        }
```

[Select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select) widget is the default widget for [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and Django renders this appropriately:

> [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)
>
> class ModelChoiceField(**kwargs)
>
> Default widget: [Select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select)

Alternatively you can use [`SelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple) and [`CheckboxSelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple).

Comment: the rendering seems to be right. I get the error messages from the validators but the Form/Object is still not stored in the db. (Form not valid)

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. I never had any problems with it. You have not specified `blank=True` in the model field def so it would require at least a value.

Comment: I still get the error that it is not iterable. But this time from the validator as an error message.

Comment: You have to be more specific, I still cannot understand. An error in a validator is irrelevant with your original question.

Comment: I have exactly the same code as you proposed now in my project. The form is now rendered as an Input-Field and the Users are listed in a DropDown-Box where I can choose only one. That's what I wanted. But when I submit the form and form.valid() is called the form error-fields are filled with the following error for the DropDown-Box `Enter a list of values.` Do you now know what I mean?

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped. Check that you are using `Select` and not `SelectMultiple` and that field is not required (either from form meta or from model `blank`).