# How to use ModelMultipleChoiceField in django-admin and django-form for SelectMultiple widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I need to use SelectMultiple widget with ModelMultipleChoiceField in Django-admin.

It's not selecting proper value in django-admin at the time of editing. Please share a working example if possible.

Thanks in advance!!!

In this issue I was not getting desired result and there was no error in my project, so this issue is different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing ManyToMany-Relation with ModelChoiceField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303947/replacing-manytomany-relation-with-modelchoicefield)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple example. If your `model.py` looks like:

```
class YourCategory(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.category_name

class YourModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    included_categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

You override in the `admin.py` the field you want as MultipleChoice:

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    included_categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            queryset = YourCategory.objects.all())#here you can filter for what choices you need

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = YourModelForm
```

Comment: I am very interested in this solution, but cannot get it to work. I assume the above code goes into admin.py of the application, right? What about "Category" Where does in come from? And TPForm?

Comment: Sorry those names were wrong. I edited the answer. Yes this goes into admin.py.

Comment: Can I do it without any model relationship involved?